# Cannot modify variable at before_save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the ff code in my Model:

```
before_save :before_save_method

attr_accessor :corrective_change
attr_accessible :corrective_change
attr_accessible :corrective_desc

  private 
    def before_save_method
      if corrective_change == 0
        self.corrective_desc = corrective_desc_was
      end
    end
```

However, whatever the value of `corrective_change` is, the value of `self.corrective_desc` still update by the input value from users.

The value of all variable are tested and I can view them in logger just fine as they should be, but the condition doesn't work.

Can anyone point out what the problem is?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1) you're sure that corrective_change is an Integer not a string? (comparing int to string = fail)

2) is this a new record? if so corrective_desc_was may not exist (it wouldnt in 2.3, not sure about 3.x)

3) consider trying this:

```
def before_save_method
  if self.corrective_desc_changed? && self.corrective_change == 0
    self.corrective_desc = self.corrective_desc_was
  else
    logger.info "corrective_desc not changed or corrective_change != 0"
  end
end
```

4) Also, if it's corrective change then perhaps before_update would be more appropriate rather than before_save as this will be called on create also.